# How to put random number generator in JTextField

Tags: java

```
JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
text1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80,80));
text1.setEditable(false);
```

By creating a slot machine, I tend to use the JField and other GUI

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _putting a random generator in JTextField_ ?  Do you need to set the text in the field to some random number?  Should this number change?

Comment: Yes, I need to set it by 1-99, then when I start the button for the slot machine, the numbers spin

Answer (score 1):

with

```
int range=*insert range*;
int random = (int) (Math.random()*range);
```

You obtain a random number between 0 and range
After this you only have to set the JTextField

```
text1.setText(""+random);
```